Subclassing scipy.stats.rv_continuous for truncated distribution
I would like to create a random variable from a truncated complementary error function.  For this I want to subclass scipy.stats.rv_continuous.  I have checked Subclassing scipy's continuous distributions and written the following code using Python 3.8.5.  It normalizes the pdf by its integral over the support, computed using quad (code edited for error in call to quad but initial bug persists ).
import numpy as np
from scipy import special

from scipy.stats import *
import scipy.stats

import scipy.integrate as integrate


class truncErfc_gen(rv_continuous):
    ''' Class for a truncated complementary error function
    a and b are bounds
    '''
    def _argcheck(self, a, b): return (a < b)

    def _get_support(self, a, b): return a, b

    def _pdf(self, x, a, b): return special.erfc(x) / integrate.quad(special.erfc, a, b)[0] # Normalization of the function over its bounds doesn't work
    #def _pdf(self, x, a, b): return special.erfc(x) # Runs, but not normalized
    
truncErfc = truncErfc_gen(name='truncErfc', momtype=1)

x = np.linspace(-1, 10, 1000)

y = truncErfc.pdf(x, a=0., b=10.)

However, I am getting the error message :
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

The error comes form the integration call used to normalize the pdf.
Any suggestions?
Full traceback
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c111ab60c209> in <module>
     23 x = np.linspace(-1, 10, 1000)
     24 
---> 25 y = truncErfc.pdf(x, a=0., b=10.)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py in pdf(self, x, *args, **kwds)
   1767             goodargs = argsreduce(cond, *((x,)+args+(scale,)))
   1768             scale, goodargs = goodargs[-1], goodargs[:-1]
-> 1769             place(output, cond, self._pdf(*goodargs) / scale)
   1770         if output.ndim == 0:
   1771             return output[()]

<ipython-input-1-c111ab60c209> in _pdf(self, x, a, b)
     16     def _get_support(self, a, b): return a, b
     17 
---> 18     def _pdf(self, x, a, b): return special.erfc(x) / integrate.quad(special.erfc, a, b)[0] # Normalization of the function over its bounds doesn't work
     19     #def _pdf(self, x, a, b): return special.erfc(x) # Runs, but not normalized
     20 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    346 
    347     # check the limits of integration: \int_a^b, expect a < b
--> 348     flip, a, b = b < a, min(a, b), max(a, b)
    349 
    350     if weight is None:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()


Note that if you attempt to find the CDF at any point in this distribution, it will be very slow, because it will use quad() to integrate the PDF to get the CDF, which will call quad() again to find total area of the distribution. Using quad()  within quad() is very slow. You can avoid quad() here by using the analytical integral rather than the numerical integral: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+erfc%28x%29+from+a+to+b That will make this distribution much faster.

The method quad accept a Callable, but you provided a computed array.
Just provide the function, it will work as expected:
def _pdf(self, x, a, b): return special.erfc(x) / integrate.quad(special.erfc, a, b)[0]


Thanks - you are right that I wasn't calling quad properly (now edited), but even rectifying that, the original problem remains.

Your code run fine on latest version of scipy. Please update your post with the full traceback of the error.

Traceback added

Interesting, I cannot reproduce this error. It runs fine here with the modification. Can you print a and b within the _pdf function, it seems quad receive arrays instead of floats. Also what is your scipy version?

scipy 1.5.2 and am running from JupyterLab

When I print a and b in the _pdf function, I get numpy arrays each of length of x in the _pdf.  Each value is the expected value but repeated to make an array ie [a, a, a, a].  One minor curiosity is that the x in the function is missing the first element from what is defined outside the function.

Problem solved by updating to scipy-1.10.1.  Thanks!

Problem solved by upgrading from scipy 1.5.2 to scipy 1.10.1 (@jlandercy).
Below is accelerated code based on @nick-odell's comment:
class truncErfc_gen(rv_continuous):
    ''' Class for a truncated complementary error function
    Normalization of pdf did not work for scipy 1.5.2, but does for scipy 1.10.1
    a and b are bounds
    '''
    def _argcheck(self, a, b): return (a < b)

    def _get_support(self, a, b): return a, b
    
    def _integErfc(self, a, b): return (np.exp(-a*a) - np.exp(-b*b)) / np.sqrt(np.pi) + b * special.erfc(b) - a * special.erfc(a) # This analytical method is faster than numerical integration

    #def _pdf(self, x, a, b): return special.erfc(x) / integrate.quad(special.erfc, a, b)[0] # Slow normalization
    def _pdf(self, x, a, b): return special.erfc(x) / self._integErfc( a, b) # Faster normalization


